# Assembly code that prints all elements of an array

Tags: assembly, x86

I've been trying print elements of an array. I've got this code that sums all elements of an array and prints the result and I tried to edit in a lot of ways with no luck.

Here is the code I found on internet:

```
    section .text
    global _start   ;must be declared for linker (ld)
_start: 

      mov  eax,3      ;number bytes to be summed 
      mov  ebx,0      ;EBX will store the sum
      mov  ecx, x     ;ECX will point to the current element to be summed
top:  add  ebx, [ecx]
      add  ecx,1      ;move pointer to next element
      dec  eax        ;decrement counter
      jnz  top        ;if counter not 0, then loop again
done: 
      add   ebx, '0'
      mov  [sum], ebx ;done, store result in "sum"
display:
      mov  edx,1      ;message length
      mov  ecx, sum   ;message to write
      mov  ebx, 1     ;file descriptor (stdout)
      mov  eax, 4     ;system call number (sys_write)
      int  0x80       ;call kernel
      mov  eax, 1     ;system call number (sys_exit)
      int  0x80       ;call kernel

section .data
global x
x:    
      db  2
      db  4
      db  3
sum: 
      db  0
```

And here is how I edited it with no luck (I tried lots of other things). This prints the first element '2' and gives *Segmentation fault* error.

EDIT: This is the working code, thanks everyone, thanks ElderBug! :)

```
_start: 

      mov  esi,3      ;number bytes to be traversed 
      mov  edi, x     ;EDI will point to the current element to be summed
      mov  eax, 0     ;eax will hold the text to print

top:  

      mov eax, [edi] ;store current element
      add  edi,1      ;move pointer to next element

      add  eax, '0' ;do the conversion
      mov [toprint], eax


      mov  ecx, toprint ;message to write
      mov  edx,1      ;message length
      mov  ebx, 1     ;file descriptor (stdout)
      mov  eax, 4     ;system call number (sys_write)
      int  0x80       ;call kernel



      dec  esi        ;decrement counter
      jnz  top        ;if counter not 0, then loop again

      mov  eax, 1     ;system call number (sys_exit)
      int  0x80       ;call kernel



   section  .data
    global x
    x:    
          db  2
          db  4
          db  3

   toprint:

         dw 'x'
```

I know "int 0x80" style 4 means write and first argument is stored in ebx, second in ecx, third in edx. But can't figure this out.

Comment: You can also use `esi` and `edi`. If you really run out of registers, you can save them on the stack, for example by `push`/`pop` or proper local variables. PS: you have removed the part that converts the numbers to text, so you won't like what you get anyway ;)

Comment: @Jester Hey, thanks for the clues. I've made some changes, can you look at it again? :)

Comment: Is the original code correct? `mov  ebx,0      ;EBX will store the sum` but then `mov  [sum], [ecx] ;done, store result in sum`

Comment: The ecx argument must be a pointer to characters. Your message have to be in memory.

Comment: @vandale No doubt. `mov  [sum], [ecx]` isn't even valid in x86. The correct line is `mov  [sum], ebx`.

Comment: @vandale Yes, I messed up, it was the wrong paste. I edited with the correct code, thanks.

Comment: @ElderBug Can't I just use `mov  ecx, [esi]' than?

Comment: No, that's worse, that would try to load what is at address esi, but esi doesn't contain an address. The message really need to be in memory. That also could be on the stack. You have the choice to print characters one by one, but you can also print them all a the same time.

Comment: @ElderBug Okay, I think I got it. Can you check my edited code please, why that doesn't work? That code only prints 2 and gives 'Segmentation fault' error.

Comment: First, you increment edi right away, so the first element will be skipped. Then you use eax as a counter, but also as parameter for sys_write, and sys_write will also change eax. Use esi as counter, and eax where you use esi (you don't need to preserve the element). Also, maybe you should use sys_exit at the end, currently you are sending the CPU into oblivion.

Comment: Thanks @ElderBug! I got it working!

Now I'm scared to ask because this probably needs more complicated work but is there an easy way I can write each number in separate line instead of all in same line?

Comment: Really easy. Before that, `toprint` should be a character, so use db. To add a new line, add a `db '\n'`,  after `db 'x'`, and use 2 as message length. Note that the "add '0'" trick to convert to ASCII only works if the number is < 10.

Comment: @cbt You can use all of `toprint` to both indent and append a newline for your numbers. You have 4-bytes, use them `:)` Try `dw '  ', 0xa`, then instead of `eax`, `mov     [toprint + 1], al`, and finally, print all bytes `mov     edx, 3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution that you say is working for you still has severe issues!

- Because *toprint* was defined as a **word** you should not write a **dword** value in it with the instruction `mov [toprint], eax`.
- Because the array elements are defined as **byte** you should not read them as **dword** with the instruction `mov eax, [edi] ;store current element`.
- sys_exit uses EBX as a 2nd parameter.

This is how it should look like

```
top:  
 mov al, [edi]     ;store current element
 add edi, 1        ;move pointer to next element
 add al, '0'       ;do the conversion
 mov [toprint], al
```

Please study the commentary given by @David C. Rankin. It's very useful for your purpose.